# Boltzmann equation and the meaning of the marginals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics

I have a question related to the boltzmann equation and the meaning
of the marginals.

Let me first introdiuce the model and notation :

(see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5753)

We study the evolution of a gaz of particles $Z_{N}(t)=(X_{1}(t),V_{1}(t),X_{2}(t),V_{2}(t)...X_{N}(t),V_{N}(t))$
evolving according to a Hamilton Jacobi equation with a defined hamiltonien
$H$. Because of the indistinguability we focus on

$$
\mu_{N}(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}\delta_{X_{i}(t),V_{i}(t)}
$$

At $t=0$, the exact initial is not known, but is chosen randomly
according to a $N$ particles distributions $f_{N}(X_{1},V_{1},X_{2},V_{2},...)$.

The probability of finding the particles for $t>0$, evolving after
the initials condition is then given by a $f_{N}(Z_{N},t)$ which
follow the Liouville equation. We then define de first marginal :

$$
f_{N}^{(1)}(X_{1},V_{1},t)=\int f_{N}(X_{1},V_{1},X_{2},V_{2},...,X_{N},V_{N})dX_{2}dV_{2}...dX_{N}dV_{N}
$$

Now here is my question : Can we justify the statement : `` $f_{N}^{(1)}$
is the related distribution of the empirical measure $\mu_{N}$.'' ?
And is it really the object physics use '' ?

Why is it not obvious ?  $f^{(1)}$ is a microscopic function average over the
initial condition. while the ``mesoscopics density'' of the physicists is for one initial condition
the average over a not too small domain.

Let take a example. The domain is a torus and let define $f_{N}$
as follow a point $p$ is chosen randomly uniformly over the domain,
then the $N$ particles are put independently in a small sphere around
$p$. In this model because of the symmetry $f^{(1)}$ is constant over all the torus but $\mu_{N}$ is supported over a small sphere a s.

So the two of them are different. What we know is that if at $t=0$ particles are completely independent
then they are equal because of the strong law of large number
but for general dynamics this should not be true for $t>0$.

Do any one know some rigorous result over the relation between the two objects
? Or an approach of Boltzmann equation using directly the ``mesoscopic function''
instead of the marginals?

Comment: isn't this the essence of the [ergodic hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis) --- averages over initial conditions are equivalent to temporal or spatial averages?

Comment: The effective independence for positive time is usually referred to as "propagation of chaos" (and obtaining it for a large enough time interval is the main contribution of the paper you link to). There are a few methods to prove such a result, but it is never trivial ...

Comment: This question possibly needs to be migrated to Physics SE.